# How can i make words in my javascript array into a link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a searchbar that autofills the words, i want to make the autofilled words links. so i have a page called page2.html and i want it so that if i type locations it will autofill the word locations en when i click on the autofilled word it will direct me to my Page2.html.

If i go to my searchbar and type Locations i get nothing, if i type "<" i get the code. it doesnt make it a link.

This is my html/javascript, there is a code that targets the arry down at the bottom:

```
  <form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="SearchBar">
        <input id="myInput" type="text" name="Search2" placeholder="Search...">
      </div>
    </form>

    <script>

 var SW = ["<a href='Page2.html'>Locations</a>"];

    function SearchBar(inp, arr) {

 var currentFocus;
 inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
     var a, b, i, val = this.value;

     closeAllLists();
     if (!val) { return false;}
     currentFocus = -1;

     a = document.createElement("DIV");
     a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "SearchBar-list");
     a.setAttribute("class", "SearchBar-items");

     this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

     for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

       if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {

         b = document.createElement("DIV");

         b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
         b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);

         b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";

             b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

             inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

             closeAllLists();
         });
         a.appendChild(b);
       }
     }
 });

 inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
     var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "SearchBar-list");
     if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
     if (e.keyCode == 40) {

       currentFocus++;

       addActive(x);
     } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {

       currentFocus--;

       addActive(x);
     } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {

       e.preventDefault();
       if (currentFocus > -1) {

         if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
       }
     }
 });
 function addActive(x) {

   if (!x) return false;

   removeActive(x);
   if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
   if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);

   x[currentFocus].classList.add("SearchBar-active");
 }
 function removeActive(x) {

   for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].classList.remove("SearchBar-active");
   }
 }
 function closeAllLists(elmnt) {

   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("SearchBar-items");
   for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
     x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
   }
 }
 }

 document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
   closeAllLists(e.target);
 });
 }
    </script>

    <script>
 SearchBar(document.getElementById("myInput"), SW);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the suggestion items using `document.createElement`.
Like this:

```js
var SW = ["Locations", "test"];
var links = ["https://shadowlp174.4lima.de","https://stackoverflow.com"];

function SearchBar(inp, arr, links) {
  var currentFocus;
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var div, b, i, val = this.value;

    closeAllLists();
    if (!val) {
      return false;
    }
    currentFocus = -1;

    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = this.id + "SearchBar-list";
    div.classList.add("SearchBar-items");
    this.parentNode.appendChild(div);

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = links[i];
        a.setAttribute("suggestion", arr[i]);
        div.appendChild(a);

        let strong = document.createElement("strong");
        strong.innerHTML = arr[i].substr(0, val.length);
        let span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = arr[i].substr(val.length, arr[i].length - 1);
        a.appendChild(strong);
        a.appendChild(span);

        a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          inp.value = this.getAttribute("suggestion");
          closeAllLists();
        });
      }
    }
  });

  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "SearchBar-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {

      currentFocus++;

      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {

      currentFocus--;

      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {

      e.preventDefault();
      if (currentFocus > -1) {

        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
      }
    }
  });

  function addActive(x) {

    if (!x) return false;

    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);

    x[currentFocus].classList.add("SearchBar-active");
  }

  function removeActive(x) {

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("SearchBar-active");
    }
  }

  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("SearchBar-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}
SearchBar(document.getElementById("myInput"), SW, links);
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="SearchBar">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="Search2" placeholder="Search...">
  </div>
</form>
```

You can set the destinations in the array. I set it to two demo sites which are available to everyone.

Comment: Thanks al lot, but csn you give me the whole code please. i am just getting started with coding and a friend helped me with this. Thank you so much :0

Comment: oh of course just a sec...

Comment: @Thomas I added a working snippet... I added my solution and changed some things... like you don't need to use 'setAttribute' for standard attributes like id or so. This can be used for custom attributes. Let me know if you need something else ;)

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: I had to rename some divs and edit the css and now its looking good and most importantly, its working too! TYSM

Comment: Nice Glad I could help. :)

Comment: i just tried to add a second suggestion, so that when i search "World wonders" i go to Page3.html, but how do i add a second one. i tried repeating the array but it wasn't that easy. can you help me out?

Comment: Np, so it works now with multiple links? Just curious

Comment: it doesn't, if i add more only the last one i add works.

Comment: Try to create an array with links like the suggestions. Note that every suggestion must have the same index as the link. And just replace “a.href = linkTarget” with “a.href = linkArr[i];” This should work :)

Comment: I’ll edit the answer so you have a working example @Thomas

Comment: i copied your example but if i open my website and type "locations or ""test" in my searchbar is am not getting any suggestions, i dont really understand what i need to replace-_-

Comment: oh wait i got it, i replaced the wrong thing. all suggestions work and they go to the links i want them to go to. i have 3 now and they all work. youre amazing thanks

Comment: nice :) Have fun!